# Subversion Merge using svnmerge.py tool

Tags: svn

Can any body let me know how to use svnmerge.py on branches, I googled out many but did not work well,some where I am doing wrong,

I have a branch called http://svnrepository/mitrac/bldtest1 and bldtest2 branches, I need to merge some revisions from bldtest1 to bldtest2 and block some revisions,Please let me know step by step procedure,I really appreciate if you give me a step by step approach.

Thanks
Pravin

Answer (score 1):

`svnmerge.py` was used for pre 1.5 versions of subversion in order to achieve 'merge tracking'. For version 1.5 and later 'merge tracking' is built into subversion.

```
svn checkout http://svnrepository/mitrac/bldtest1
cd bldtest1
svn merge -r45:50 http://svnrepository/mitrac/bldtest2
svn merge -r53:55 http://svnrepository/mitrac/bldtest2
svn ci -m"Revision 45:50 and 53:55 merged"
```

Using this approach you just merge 'desired' revision.

Use `svn revert` to undo unwanted changes.

Comment: So it means if I use just svn merge am I good, I am using svn 1.6.6 in my local machine where I do svn operations, svn --version
svn, version 1.6.6 (r40053),but if I use some other server if I hit svn --version it says 1.4.2,Now  if I use just svn merge is that fine,Can you please advice.

Comment: I need svnmerge.py step by step to merge two branch changes so tool can able to block some revisions,any chance I can get step by step procedure to use svnmerge.py tool

Answer (score 1):

under bldtest2 branch issue this

```
$ svnmerge.py init http://svnrepository/mitrac/bldtest1
```

Once you have initialized the branch to fetch the updates from the repository you can then issue commands like svnmerge.py avail to see any incoming revisions to be applied... You can find most of them at the [svnmerge.py wiki](http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Svnmerge.py).