# merging two subversion branches

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

i found conflicting procedures:

[Subversion merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127427/subversion-merge-using-svnmerge-py-tool)

```
  svn checkout http://a.b.c/bldtest1
  cd bldtest1
  svn merge -r45:50 http://a.b.c/bldtest2
  svn merge -r53:55 http://a.b.c/bldtest2
  svn ci -m "Revision 45:50 and 53:55 merged"
```

[Merge between two branches in subversion](http://blog.e-shell.org/192)

```
$ svn merge -r 127:240 svn+ssh://svn.myproject.org/svn/trunk .
```

WHICH one of these is the right one ? as they are opposite of each other.
provided we find the set of revisions to be merged with :

```
svn log --verbose --stop-on-copy  branch1 > log.txt
```

so in order to merge branch1 TO branch2, do we:

```
1. svn co branch1
3. cd branch1
4. svn merge -r xx:yy branch2
```

OR

```
1. svn co branch1
2. svn co branch2
3. cd branch2
4. svn merge -r xx:yy branch1 .
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation? [Chapter 4 - Branching and Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These procedures **are not conflicted**: in first sample default target "." just omitted

> in order to merge branch1 TO branch2

You have to:

Read and understand SVN Book (link provided by Sameer)

Use **correct way** of merging

```
svn co URL/TO/branch2
cd branch2
svn merge -r xx:yy URL/TO/branch1
```

And, BTW, cherry-pick merging isn't best merging in the world

Comment: Hello Sir, could you please take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36157555/3287204)? Thanks in advance ... :)